# Failed to move file to C:\xampp\tmp\e3bB6FA.tmp

Tags: php

I keep having this warning after uploading image.

I have tried to change many times the path of `sys_temp_dir` and `upload_tmp_dir` in `php.ini`. But it's still not working.

Does anybody know to solve this?

Comment: Post the code..

Comment: Just to be clear, did You reload config/restart Your apache server?

Comment: yes i did many imes

Comment: Please show us your code. Do you really mean that the error is that you can't move _to_ the tmp folder? Don't you mean move _from_ the tmp folder? I would suspect that you've switched some variables around in some call.